# How to insert a link in an e-mail VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have created a macro that sends e-mails to certain people when a condition is filled. However, In the body of the e-mail I would like to insert a link like so `Link` instead of  `http://blabla.com`.

Do you know how I could make that happen ?

The link is on my cell B4, and this is the following code.

```
Public Sub email_missing_forecast()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Déclaration des variables

derniereligne = Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
Project_number = Cells(1, 2).Value
Project_name = Cells(2, 2).Value
Project_due = Cells(3, 2).Value
lien = Cells(4, 2).Value

Dim Objoutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim Objectmail

'Condition

For i = 6 To derniereligne

Adresse = Cells(i, "D").Value
Adresse2 = Cells(i, "E").Value
Adresse3 = Cells(i, "F").Value

If Cells(i, "B").Value = "No" Then
    Set Objoutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set Objectmail = Outlook.createitem(olmailitem)

        With Objectmail
        .To = Adresse & ";" & Adresse2 & ";" & Adresse3
        .Subject = "Bobbi Brown | " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " | Forecast due " & Project_due
        .Body = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " are due " & Project_due & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please enter your forecast at the link below." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & lien & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards," & Chr(10) & "Christian Chen"
        .Send

End With
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Your e-mails have been sent successfully", , "FIY"
End Sub
```

Comment: How's your html? If you replace `.Body` with `.HTMLBody` you can type all of your body in html format, you can use `<a href="www.example.com">LinkText</a>` to show a link instead of a URL.

Comment: A good example of what @Jordan is talking about! http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/492801-putting-active-link-htmlbody-cdo-2.html#post2435236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML body can be used to get this. Please use the below lines in your code. enter these lines below Set Objectmail = Outlook.createitem(olmailitem)

```
strbody = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " are due " & Project_due & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please enter your forecast at the link below." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & lien & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards," & Chr(10) & "Christian Chen"
```

Once you type the above lines, just remove

`.Body = "Dear All, " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "I kindly remind you that forecasts for program " & Project_number & " " & Project_name & " are due " & Project_due & "." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please enter your forecast at the link below." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & lien & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Best Regards," & Chr(10) & "Christian Chen"` 
and add

`.HTMLBody = StrBody & "<a href=""" & ActiveSheet.Range("B4") & """ >Name your link</a>"`

Comment: On line 2 of your code I think you may need to replace `"<A href=http://enter the link>Give name for your link</A>"` with `"<a href=""https://enter the link"">Give name for your link</a>"`

Comment: I do have to rewrite all my body to fit the .HTMLBody ? And also how can I use the link in the cell instead of typing the link in the macro ?

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my answer as per your requirement. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much !