# VBA convert ThisWorkbook.Path to Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, path

i try to send an email via VBA. This email contains the path to the file. But the path is not shown as link to the folder where the file is stored. To be honest i have no idea how to solve this problem and i could not find any solutions so far.

My Code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim outlookOBJ As Object
    Dim mItem As Object
    Set outlookOBJ = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mItem = outlookOBJ.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With mItem
        .To = "Mail.Adress@test.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "Text Text Text" & ThisWorkbook.Path
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        .Send

    End With
End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me that the path will be a clickable link in my email.

thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020684/how-to-insert-a-link-in-an-e-mail-vba-excel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) will help ?

Comment: unfortunately not really, i tried it already. But if i add the `<a href= `then it only creates a hyperlink to an URL

Comment: Well, sorry I do not understand what you are asking. You said "when the path is not shown as link"

Comment: oh okay .. sorry for my unclear question .. i want a link that opens the folder where the file is stored.

Comment: So, as you send a mail, you could say the file is shared, like on a server, but you use `.attachements.Add` so the file may be attached to the email ? Do you give a clickable link or/and do you send the file in the email ?

Comment: right, the file is shared on a server and i my mail i want that the file is attached and a clickable link to the folder where the file is stored

Comment: Ok, you do both. I would like to suggest that the url has to be absolute, for example if you use `G:\file\document.doc` for example, you may use the real server name `ServerName\file\document.doc`. Url to local storage or files in servers does works. To be sure the path is good, you juste have to copy/paste the path name in your browser. If this is not the problem, can you add some details ?